# How to populate spinner from cursorloader?

Tags: spinner, android-cursorloader

I have spent days to figure this out but no luck. Wish I could get answer from here.
I tried to load data into spinner from my content provider using the cursorLoader method.
The spinner seem had received the data but I found no data in the dropdown list, although several dropdown items (with no text) had been created.

I believe problem is not from my provider because if I use the same cursor to retrieve the data and put it into array, then bind the array to the spinner, then it shows all items correctly.

Below is my code,

```
package com.supreme2u.shopper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.supreme2u.shopper.provider.ShopperProvider;

public class RecordActivity extends Activity  implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>  {
private SimpleCursorAdapter sAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_record);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);     
    sAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            null, 
            new String[] {ShopperProvider.TAG_COLUMN_TAG}, 
            new int[] {R.id.spinner1},
            0);
    sAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    Spinner v = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    v.setAdapter(sAdapter);
}

public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
            this, 
            ShopperProvider.CONTENT_URI_TAGS, 
            ShopperProvider.TAG_COLUMNS, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null);
    return cursorLoader;
}

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
    sAdapter.swapCursor(arg1);
}

public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    sAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}

}
```

And my layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And from my ShopperProvider class, extracted,

```
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_TAGS = Uri.parse("content://com.supreme2u.shopper.provider/tableTag");

public static final String TAG_COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String TAG_COLUMN_TAG = "tagName";
public static final String[] TAG_COLUMNS = {"_id","tagName"};
```

Comment: Got it... (everytime only after posted question, then only found out the stupid mistake)...the view that the sAdapter should bind to, is not R.id.spinner1, but android.R.id.text1.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your construction of the SimpleCursorAdapter, specifically the second and fifth parameters (*layout* and *to*). From the docs:

> *layout*: resource identifier of a layout file that defines the views for this list item. The layout file should include at least those named views defined in "to"
>
> *to*: The views that should display column in the "from" parameter. These should all be TextViews. The first N views in this list are given the values of the first N columns in the from parameter.  Can be null if the cursor is not available yet.

So you are correct to use *android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item* for *layout*. However, the views passed for *to* need to be TextViews and contained within *android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item*: i.e. *android.R.id.text1* instead of *R.id.spinner1*.

In short, use this construction instead:

```
sAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
        null, 
        new String[] {ShopperProvider.TAG_COLUMN_TAG}, 
        new int[] {android.R.id.text1},
        0);
```