# Getting XML-file from url gives wrong output

Tags: xml-parsing, jsoup

I am at my wits end with this peculiar question. I am trying to download (or make a copy) of a xml-file from a url to my android phone (Desire HD v2.3.3). It should work out of the box according to many people at SOF but no matter how I try and what tutorial I follow, it simply doesn't work. I do not get the desired xml file as far as I know.

logcat does not show anything peculiar and I follow my code with string messages.

Here Below is my code:

```
private void programXmlExists() {
        //Kontrollerar om XML-filern Program.xml existerar annars skall den laddas ner.
        //Om filen existerar, så skall filens timestamp jämföras med dagens. Är det större skillnad än kl. 00.00
        //så skall en ny uppdatering ske.
        if(xmlFileExistence("Program.xml")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "1) Program.xml exists ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println("1) File exists");
            //Filen Program.xml existerar. Kolla om filens timestamp är yngre än 00.00 Om så ej är fallet, så skall en uppdaterad version
            //hämtas från servern
            File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath("Program.xml");
            file = new File(this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "Program.xml");
            long date = file.lastModified();
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Date: "+date, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //Glöm ej att radera den gamla Program.xml om den behöver uppdateras
            //deleteFile("Program.xml");

            //downloaderThread = new Thread(this, "http://ken.nu/projekt/Program.xml");
            //downloaderThread.start();             
            /**
             * Connects to the URL of the file, begins the download, and notifies the
             * AndroidFileDownloader activity of changes in state. Writes the file to
             * the root of the SD card.
             */

            URL url = null;
            URLConnection conn = null;
            int fileSize, lastSlash;
            String fileName;
            BufferedInputStream inStream = null;;
            BufferedOutputStream outStream = null;;
            File outFile;
            FileOutputStream fileStream = null;
            Message msg;

            // We're going to connect now
            try {
                url = new URL("http://ken.nu/projekt/Program.xml");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                conn = url.openConnection();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            fileSize = conn.getContentLength();

            // get the filename
            lastSlash = url.toString().lastIndexOf('/');
            fileName = "Program.xml";
            if(lastSlash >=0)
            {
                    fileName = url.toString().substring(lastSlash + 1);
            }
            if(fileName.equals(""))
            {
                    fileName = "Program.xml";
            }

         // start download
            try {
                inStream = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + fileName);
            try {
                fileStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileStream, DOWNLOAD_BUFFER_SIZE);
            byte[] data = new byte[DOWNLOAD_BUFFER_SIZE];
            int bytesRead = 0, totalRead = 0;
            try {
                while((bytesRead = inStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) >= 0)
                {
                        outStream.write(data, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            try {
                outStream.close();
                fileStream.close();
                inStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            xmlFileExistence("Program.xml");

        }else{

            //Programs.xml finns inte. Ladda ner en ny version utav den från servern

            Toast.makeText(this, "Program.xml DOESNT exist ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println("2) Does not exist");
            File dir = getFilesDir();
            //Filen existerar inte. Hämta en ny version från servern
            String FILENAME = "Program.xml";
            // File url to download
            String file_url = "http://ken.nu/projekt/Program.xml";


            //------------
            /**
             * Connects to the URL of the file, begins the download, and notifies the
             * AndroidFileDownloader activity of changes in state. Writes the file to
             * the root of the SD card.
             */

            URL url = null;
            URLConnection conn = null;
            int fileSize, lastSlash;
            String fileName;
            BufferedInputStream inStream = null;;
            BufferedOutputStream outStream = null;;
            File outFile;
            FileOutputStream fileStream = null;
            Message msg;

            // We're going to connect now
            try {
                url = new URL("http://ken.nu/projekt/Program.xml");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                conn = url.openConnection();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            fileSize = conn.getContentLength();

            // get the filename
            lastSlash = url.toString().lastIndexOf('/');
            fileName = "Program.xml";
            if(lastSlash >=0)
            {
                    fileName = url.toString().substring(lastSlash + 1);
            }
            if(fileName.equals(""))
            {
                    fileName = "Program.xml";
            }

         // start download
            try {
                inStream = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + fileName);
            try {
                fileStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileStream, DOWNLOAD_BUFFER_SIZE);
            byte[] data = new byte[DOWNLOAD_BUFFER_SIZE];
            int bytesRead = 0, totalRead = 0;
            try {
                while((bytesRead = inStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) >= 0)
                {
                        outStream.write(data, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            try {
                outStream.close();
                fileStream.close();
                inStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            xmlFileExistence("Program.xml");
            //------------

        }
        //deleteFile("Program.xml");
        System.out.println("3) End");
}
```

Here is the my loadSpinnerPrograms().

```
private void loadSpinnerPrograms() {
    List<String> SpinnerProgramsArray =  new ArrayList<String>();
    spinnerPrograms = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_programs);

    //Code input to spinner

    Document doc = null;

    /*
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://ken.nu/projekt/Program.xml").get();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }*/

    doc = Jsoup.parse("Program.xml", "utf-8");
    System.out.println("loadSpinnerPrograms: "+doc.toString());

    Elements id = doc.getElementsByTag("id"); //Hämta alla element som finns med tagen id
    Elements namn = doc.getElementsByTag("namn"); //Hämta alla element som finns med tagen namn

    int i = 0;
    //Denna forsats används för att få ut elementen id och namn som finns i elementen kurs
    //och lägga till dem i SpinnersArray
    for (Element e : doc.select("kurs")){
        System.out.println("id: "+id.get(i).text()+"   namn: "+namn.get(i).text());
        SpinnerProgramsArray.add(id.get(i).text()+" - "+namn.get(i).text());
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("Programs counter: "+i);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterProg = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, SpinnerProgramsArray);
    adapterProg.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinnerPrograms.setAdapter(adapterProg);
    spinnerPrograms.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    /*
     * Denna kod användes för testning när man laddade in items från en xml-.fil
    spinnerPrograms = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_programs);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterProg = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( this, R.array.programs_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); 
    adapterProg.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerPrograms.setAdapter(adapterProg);
    spinnerPrograms.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    */

}
```

What really blows my mind is that the output file gives this when I try to read the element in it. If i try to read the file, I get html-tags and in body it says Programs.xml
I want the file to contain the xml-file that was online.
Can anyone of you please help me understand where I am doing wrong? I am really at my wits end with this.

Regards, SM

Comment: This is good idea to decouple components, separate android logic from jsoup logic etc. After this is much easier to find bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Element `namn` is not always present.
- Downloaded file contains only file name!

Code for downloading file and reading xml from it:

```
byte[] bytes = Jsoup.connect("http://ken.nu/projekt/Program.xml")
        .ignoreContentType(true)
        .execute()
        .bodyAsBytes();

try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

    fos.write(bytes);
    fos.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(file, "UTF-8");

Elements kurses = doc.getElementsByTag("kurs");

for (Element kurs : kurses) {
    String id = kurs.getElementsByTag("id").first().text();
    Element namnElement = kurs.getElementsByTag("namn").first();
    String namn = namnElement != null ? namnElement.text() : "";
    System.out.println(id + " : " + namn);
}
```

Comment: Hi Mariusz!Sorry for being late with answer. Yes, your method works and that was my first attepmt at making the solution. Sorry for not clarifying this earlier.

Just as you did, when conneting to the server directly with Jsoup.connect, my code works and behaves exactly as anticipated. Everything gets nicely loaded. The downside is the amount of time it takes to parse through all of this large xml-file. This solws down my application enormously.

That's why I tried to first download the XML-file to the mobile unit and then work with it via Jsoup.parse(myXmlFile, "utf-8");

Comment: My problem as far as I understand is why the downloaded xml-file does not seem to be the one I want to download. Traversing through the document gives nothing.

Comment: For slowdown you should load xml in background, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434413/how-to-populate-spinner-from-cursorloader

Comment: Hi again, @MariuszS! Here comes the code I use to read the created Program.xml file that I get from internet.

    doc = Jsoup.parse("Program.xml", "utf-8");
    System.out.println("loadSpinnerPrograms: "+doc.toString());

Problem is that I receive some peculiar output. I get this:
<html><heda><body>Program.xml</body></html>

Thats all I can get out of the file. I use Jsoup to traverse the file according to the code in loadSpinnerProgram().

I am well underway to rewrite all of the code regarding programXmlExists(). I have worked with android for like two months and am quite green at this. /SM

Comment: You have writed string `Program.xml` into file, not downloaded file.

Comment: I am so stupid! I forgot to flush the stream. No wonder I never could get something out the created files. Dang, I've been looking att all the wrong places, hahaha. Look, I really want to thank you for your suggestions, MariuszS! Unfortunately I need 15 in reputation to be able to vote up your method for reading xml. It is good. Thanks for all. Hopefully I will manage to get the rest of this program right. Once again, thanks! /SM