# How to populate spinner using CursorLoader?

Tags: android, android-spinner, simplecursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I'm trying to populate a spinner from cursorloader.

I have an IndicatorFragment for the spinner, which I'm gonna include into some other fragments (via `<include>` tag).

---

First of all I've checked if the data is in the database (ContentProvider), and everything is OK.

---

The second step was to write an xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="@string/con_lbl_input_indicator"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:id="@+id/indicators_spinner"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
    </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

Then I've wrote the IndicatorFragment.class where I'm using `SimpleCursorAdapter` and `Loader` for populating data from the database:

```
public class IndicatorsFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

    private static final String LOG_TAG = IndicatorsFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int INDICATOR_LOADER_ID = 0;

    private Spinner spIndicator;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter spinAdapter;

    private static final String[] INDICATOR_PROJECTION = {
            ChemToolsContract.IndicatorsEntry._ID,
            ChemToolsContract.IndicatorsEntry.COLUMN_NAME
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_indicators, container, false);

        spIndicator = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.indicators_spinner);

        spinAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, null,
                new String[]{ChemToolsContract.IndicatorsEntry.COLUMN_NAME},
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1}, 0);

        spinAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spIndicator.setAdapter(spinAdapter);

        spIndicator.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(INDICATOR_LOADER_ID, null, this);
        spIndicator.setOnItemClickListener(null);
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(INDICATOR_LOADER_ID);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        Uri baseUri = ChemToolsContract.IndicatorsEntry.CONTENT_URI;

        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), baseUri, INDICATOR_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        spinAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        spinAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

And the last thing is the xml file, where I've added my fragment with the spinner using `<include>` attribute:

```
<include layout="@layout/fragment_indicators"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

But I don't see any data in the spinner when the application is started:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgi9R.png

---

So I don't know what I'm doing wrong: load data from database or include the fragment with the spinner into another?

Comment: where is your db method, in which you are getting the value of IndicatorsEntry column

Comment: I thought that Loader handles ContentProvider's query() method. Anyway this is my ContentProvider class: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b290fbaa2947982fd28d

Comment: use a debugger and check whether are you getting data from db correctly..

Comment: I have the same CursorLoader implementation that I've used in the other fragments. In those fragments everything works correctly. I think that maybe I'm doing something wrong with SimpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: in simple cursor adapter why are you passing null for cursor?

Comment: cursor holds values of database, since you are passing null no values get displayed.

Comment: I've used the same approach, but I immediately corrected his mistake (new int[] {android.R.id.text1} in SimpleCursorAdapter constructor) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434413/how-to-populate-spinner-from-cursorloader?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You must initialize the **Loader**, this line is missing. I propose to include this line:

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(INDICATOR_LOADER_ID, null, this);
```

inside of the **onCreateView** method, just above the `return rootView;` line. The method, in this case, should be like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_indicators, container, false);

    spIndicator = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.indicators_spinner);

    spinAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, null,
            new String[]{ChemToolsContract.IndicatorsEntry.COLUMN_NAME},
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1}, 0);

    spinAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spIndicator.setAdapter(spinAdapter);

    spIndicator.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(INDICATOR_LOADER_ID, null, this);
    return rootView;
}
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

It is curious that you did not run into the following error (because I did).

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner.
```

Nonetheless, a great answer from @Reynel. Just a slight edit I'd like to make. Instead of

```
spIndicator.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }
});
```

you write

```
spIndicator.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // you code here
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // you code here
    }
});
```

Taken from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31377548/4570466).